# Proof of $\overline{A} = \bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak{U}}(A + U) = \bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak{U}}\overline{A + U}$

Tags: topological-groups

**Proposition.**
Let $G$ be an abelian (probably not Hausdorff) topological group, let $A$ be a subset of $G$, and let $\mathfrak{U} = \{U\subseteq G \mbox{ : neighbourhood of }0\}$. Then, the closure $\overline{A}$ is written as
$$
\overline{A} = \bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak{U}}(A + U) = \bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak{U}}\overline{A + U}.
$$
**Question.**
I want to prove $\bigcap\overline{A + U}\subseteq \bigcap(A + U)$. Let $x\in \bigcap\overline{A + U}$, and let $U\in\mathfrak{U}$. There exists a  $U'\in \mathfrak{U}$ such that $U' + U' \subseteq U$. A PDF I'm reading says that $\overline{A + U'}\subseteq A + U' + U'$, why?

Comment: Every neighborhood $U$  of $0$ contained a symmetric ball $V$ such that $V+V\subset U$:  By continuity, there are $W,W'$ such that $W+W'\subset U$. Let $V=(W\cap W')\cap(-W)\cap(-W')$.

Comment: As for the proposition you are trying to proof: Notice that  $x\in\overline{A}$ iff $(x+V)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for any
open neighborhood $V$ of $0$, which is equivalent to  $x\in A-V$ for
every such neighborhood.  Since $V$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ iff
so is $-V$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \overline{A + U'}$, then $x - U'$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. Therefore $(x - U')\cap (A + U')\neq\varnothing$, and there exists $u$, $v\in U'$, and $a\in A$ such that $x - u = a + v$. Hence $x = a + u + v\in A + U' + U'$.